# Finding Words After The Last Vowel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to generate a list of words that rhyme with an input word according to the CMU Pronouncing dictionary I have managed to arrange all the words into a dictionary with their keys being a list of strings representing their values. However, due to something rhyming based on the last vowel, I'm sort of stuck on finding how to go about this in the case of words that contain more than one

```
def dotheyrhyme(filename,word):
    rhymes = {}
    list = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.readlines()[56:]
        for line in text:
            splitline = line.split("  ")
            rhymes[str(splitline[0])] = "".join(splitline[1:])
        f.close()
    comparer = rhymes[word.upper()].rstrip().split(" ")
    return comparer
```

I plan to use the comparer variable as a baseline and believe reversing this variable could also be a good way to go about it but I'm lost or overthinking ways to compare if the last vowel and letters after are the same and append accordingly?

Example:

```
{SECOND: 'S' 'EH1' 'K' 'AH0' 'N' 'D'}
```

Would rhyme with

```
{'AND': 'AH0' 'N' 'D'}
```

but these two wouldn't rhyme

```html
{'YELLOW': 'Y' 'EH1' 'L' 'OW0'}
```

And

```html
{HELLO: 'HH' 'AH0' 'L' 'OW1'}
```

But the methods I can't think of ways to counter varying lengths and multiple vowels.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to start comparing from the end. There are special algorithms and data structures that can help in cases like yours - you can check [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

But in the simple case, you would need to compare the words in the reverse order and find common substring above some threshold to call these words a rhyme, e.g.:

```
def if_rhymes(word1, word2):
    r1 = reverse(rhymes[word2])
    r2 = reverse(rhymes[word1])
    the_same = 0
    for sound1, sound2 in zip(r1, r2):
        if sound1 == sound2:
            the_same += 1
        else:
            break

     if the_same < threshold:
         return 'no rhyme'  # or False if you want
     else:
         return 'rhymes'  # or True
```

**What the algorithm does**

1. It takes the list of sounds from the `rhymes` dictionary that you populated from file (for clarity I recommend doing it outside the rhyme testing function).
2. Then it reverses the order of elements in lists of sounds for both words and creates a list of pairs (or tuples) using `zip`.
3. Each of the tuples (sounds from the words in the reverse order) is compared. We count the ones that are the same and stop comparing on the first different pair of sounds from the back.
4. Depending on the threshold (you may want to substitute the variable for an actual value) you consider given pair of words as a rhyme or not.

Comment: i see so since words rhyme regardless of their stress in this case utilizing the example as a base if it were to set a threshold of 2 in the case that the vowles would be considered a single string and ideally their would only be one word after the last vowel would utilizing the .replace method on the strings to get rid of the ints be a good method after i find a ideal way of determining a threshold ?

Comment: also ive come across a edge case in trying out different implementations for this code for the word yellow and hello they have pronunciations of Y EH1 L OW0 and HH AH0 L OW1 respectively so in reversing through this backwards this case passes so i'm going to attempt to formally loop through the zip unreversed as i believe if i understood your understanding right it will exit through the loop after checking each string

Comment: @Vanguard: I am sorry but it is very hard to get a grasp on what you are asking about...

Comment: no problem, i think i solved it utilizing replace and continue so that i can work around words that end in vowels. I'm now trying to find  way to open the dictionary and use this function together  so that it runs within a certain time frame but thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Vanguard: if the answer helped please mark it with the green tick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Finding last vowel requires you to have a set of vowels. After that you only got to iterate over the list backwards.

```
vowels = {...} # some list of vowels
word = ['S', 'EH1', 'K', 'AH0', 'N', 'D']

for i in word[::-1]:
    if i in vowels:
        last_vowel = i
        break
```

If open to other idea you can also look at this library which finds the rhymes for you : https://pypi.org/project/pronouncing/

Comment: i see thanks, but in the case of me comparing two words of varying lengths can i determine if they rhyme by checking if the index from the list element of the last vowel to the end of the list match. im currently having trouble with the words hello : HH AH0 L OW1 and yellow: Y EH1 L OW0 which don't rhyme but i'm having trouble in implementing my reasoning into code as the last vowel doesn't contain any sounds leaving it just to the other Vowels